# zk how to generate component within zul by for each or template, with mvvm?

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, mvvm, zk

my boss want me to make menu like bootstrap with zk, and i have learned to make it from [here](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Theming_and_Styling/ZK_Official_Themes/ZK_Bootstrap_Theme)

now i want to make menu like this [image]

but i want to generate every panel with code so it setting able hehehe, i use mvvm method, already have viewmodel that work with listbox but not work with mine

here is the code

```
<zk id="index" xmlns:n="native" >
    <div class="page-header text-center">
        <n:h1>ZK Bootstrap Evshop </n:h1>
        <n:h5>This version is newborn, say something bad about it and i will slap you </n:h5>
    </div>

    <div class="container" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('controller.MenuViewModel')">
        <navbar mold="bs-tabs" id="mainTabs">
            <navitem label="Home" selected="true" />
            <navitem label="ktek"/>
        </navbar>

<!--        normal listbox work really well-->
        <listbox id="carListbox" height="160px" model="@load(vm.menuList)" emptyMessage="No car found in the result" >
            <listhead>
                <listheader label="Model" />
                <listheader label="Make" />
                <listheader label="Price" width="20%"/>
            </listhead>
            <template name="model">
                <listitem>
                    <listcell label="@init(each.title)"></listcell>
                    <listcell label="@init(each.icon)" ></listcell>
                    <listcell>$<label value="@init(each.id)" />
                    </listcell>
                </listitem>
            </template>
        </listbox>

<!--        container with model doesnt even showing anything-->
        <div class="container" model="@load(vm.menuList)">
            <div class="row" id="main1">
                <template name="model">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                        <panel title="@init(each.title)">
                            <panelchildren>
                                <n:img src="@init(each.icon)"  alt="zk logo" width="50px" height="50px"></n:img>
                                <button id="@init(each.id)" width="75%">Go</button>
                            </panelchildren>
                        </panel>
                    </div>    
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>

<!--        trying to use for each, still not good enough-->
        <zk forEach="@load(vm.menuList)">
            <div class="row" id="main">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                    <panel title="@init(each.title)">
                        <panelchildren>
                            <n:img src="@init(each.icon)"  alt="zk logo" width="50px" height="50px"></n:img>
                            <button id="@init(each.id)" width="75%">Go</button>
                        </panelchildren>
                    </panel>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </zk>

    </div> 
</zk>
```

this is how it look like 
[image]

any suggestion friend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than `listbox`, `div` does not have a model, and I would have expected an error message to be honest.

Anyway, by changing the binding from `model` to [`children`](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/data_binding/children_binding.html) you can get it to work. You have to move the binding from your `container` to the `row` (template has to be a child of the component with the model/children binding):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="main1" children="@load(vm.menuList)">
        <template name="children">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                <panel title="@init(each.title)">
                    <panelchildren>
                        <button id="@init(each.id)" width="75%">Go</button>
                    </panelchildren>
                </panel>
            </div>    
        </template>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will produce a panel and button for each element in `menuList`.

Comment: it works thanks a lot, you have save me for second time hehehe

Comment: i try to add the icon to but it doesn't showing, is there a code like  src="@init(each.icon).toString"? actually the each.icon contain path of the icon that want to to be showed

Comment: It should work as long `each.icon` returns a valid path. Can you check in the DOM whether the image is added and just cannot resolve the path or whether there is no image tag produced? And why are you using the native namespace here? Could you also try whether using the "normal" `image` tag works?

Comment: i did it but have to use zscript like this <panelchildren>
                                <zscript>
                                    String icon = each.icon.toString();
                                </zscript>
                                <n:img src="${icon}"  alt="zk logo" width="50px" height="50px"></n:img>
                                <button id="@init(each.id)" width="75%">Go</button>
                            </panelchildren>

Comment: ooh so i can use normal tag image, thanks for the hint i will try

Comment: Well, I have just tried adding your `n:img` tag and this is what zk makes of it: `<img id="z_i" src="@init(each.icon)" ...>`. Seems like binding doesn't work with native elements. This is obvious as the [native elements do not create components on the server](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/HTML_Tags/The_native_Namespace#Dynamic_Update). Hence, zk does not have access to bind.

Comment: and as you said when i use normal image tag it works, it doesn't need the zscript. thanks a lot it much more easier